Python - SPARQWrapper returns me a XML file when I request a CSV file. Need help converting the data into an SQL table
I wrote this code to get names of all gen 1 pokemon from Wikidata, which I then want to turn into a SQL table.
```python
sparql = SPARQLWrapper("https://query.wikidata.org/sparql")

sparql.setQuery("""
PREFIX wd: <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/>
PREFIX wdt: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/>
PREFIX wikibase: <http://wikiba.se/ontology#>

SELECT DISTINCT ?pokemon ?pokemonLabel
WHERE {
  ?pokemon wdt:P361 wd:Q3245450.
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE]". }
}""")

sparql.setReturnFormat(CSV)

result = sparql.query().convert()

pandas.read_csv(result).to_sql('PokemonDBP', conn, if_exists = 'replace', index = False)
```

However, the code returns a ValueError, Invalid file path or buffer object type: <class 'xml.dom.minidom.Document'>. It seems like SPARQLWrapper cannot return the data from Wikidata in a CSV format?
I tried rewriting the code to return JSON, and then created a loop to check if the data was recorded properly:
```python
sparql.setReturnFormat(JSON)

result = sparql.query().convert()
for res in result["results"]["bindings"]:
        print(res["pokemonLabel"]["value"], 
              res["pokemon"]["value"])
```

However, while the results on the Wikidata query on their website look like this:
pokemon      pokemonLabel 
wd:Q2488577    Muk
wd:Q2739523    Golem
...
the results of this loop look like this:
Q2485997 http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q2485997
Q2486013 http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q2486013
...
I would appreciate any help and suggestions on how I can turn the results of this SPARQL query into an SQL table.

Have you tried this solution?

you have to force CSV content from Wikidata via sparql.setOnlyConneg(True) in your code. Next, you have to convert from the CSV in a buffer to data:  data = io.BytesIO(result) - then you can load that CSV data into a dataframe pandas.read_csv(data) and work on your SQL table loading.

@UninformedUser I tried using that, but then I get an error telling me there is no data to parse from

I have found a solution to my issue after browsing Stack Overflow some more.
I changed this line:
SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE]".

to this line:
?pokemon rdfs:label ?pokemonLabel. filter(lang(?pokemonLabel) = "en").

Link to the post I found the solution in

You can parse the html from request:
from requests_html import HTMLSession
from html.parser import HTMLParser

url ="https://m.wikidata.org/wiki/Q3245450"
session = HTMLSession()

r = session.get(url)
#print(len(r.html.absolute_links))
poke=[]
for e in r.html.absolute_links:
    if 'https://m.wikidata.org/wiki/Q' in e and len(e) == 36:
        poke.append(e)


def pok_char(url):
    session = HTMLSession()
    res = session.get(url)
    
    class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
        def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
            if tag == 'meta' and ('property', 'og:title') in attrs:
                print(attrs[1][1])
    
    parser = MyHTMLParser()
    parser.feed(res.text)

for li in poke:
    pok_char(li)


Thank you for your suggestions. The solution you linked in the comment did not fix the issue, unfortunately. As for html parsing, I appreciate it, but I would strongly prefer a solution that involves using SPARQL, as that is the skill I am currently practicing.
